# Closing windows when calling multiple functions

Tags: python, pysimplegui

So I'm practicing with PySimpleGui and creating a character sheet. I've got a button that triggers the top "if event" but when the create_name function returns 'name' the window does not close and I get the next functions window opening and ending up with multiple windows open. Is there a way to close the window as part of the return function or a simpler way to transition to the new function?

```
        if event == 'Create New Character':
            player_character.character_name = create_name()
            player_character.selected_profession = create_profession()

def create_name():
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Enter your character name: ')],
        [sg.InputText('', key='name_text')],
        [sg.Button('Continue'), sg.Exit()]
    ]

    window = sg.Window('MERP Character Creation', layout)

    while True:
        event, values = window.Read()
        if event is None or event == 'Exit':
            break

        if event == 'Continue':
            name = values['name_text'] 
            return name


    window.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep statement `window.close()` before you `return`

Two example for it, remember that `window.close()` does not mean end of function.

```py
    while True:

        event, values = window.read()
        if event is None or event == 'Exit':
            break

        if event == 'Continue':
            name = values['name_text']
            window.close()
            return name

    window.close()
```

```py
    while True:

        event, values = window.read()
        if event is None or event == 'Exit':
            result = None
            break

        if event == 'Continue':
            result = values['name_text']
            break

    window.close()
    return result
```